# Reset all Customer Password Module?

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.4.6

Is there a module that notifies users after logging in that they have to change their password?
Or a possibility to reset the passwords of the users that a new one has to be set after next login ?

Thanks for the help.

Greeting

Answer (score 0):

**Forced Password Change by Magenest** - This module allows you to force users to change their password after a certain period of time or on their next login.